# XCode C++ Standard Library: libc++ won't build. libstdc++ does

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, libstdc++, libc++

Having some strange issues with a large iOS project I'm working on. I have tried to add a static library to the project and I get the following errors during linking:

[XCode Error (Sorry I don't have enough reputation to post images inline!)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nc95k.png)

G4XSwiper is not the library I added however it seems to be causing the error.

The strange part is when I go into the build settings and change the C++ Standard Library from libc++ to libstdc++ it builds and runs fine. To be totally honest I'm not even sure what this setting means or does.

What could be the issue here? I've been pulling my hair out for two days on this. We have a lot of frameworks we depend on, is it likely we will run into problems by making this switch?

Comment: G4XSwiper has been built with libstdc++, which used to be the default in XCode many years ago. You need to rebuild it with libc++.

Comment: But the project was building just fine before. I didn't add the G4XSwiper library. G4XSwiper is a 3rd party library, is there anyway for me to rebuild it on my own? I'm assuming they would have to do it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library. You'll have to check the docs. Look for the section called "building from source".

Comment: Shoot. Thanks for the help. Do you know why adding a new totally separate library would break the G4XSwiper library that has always been included? Wouldn't this have been an issue regardless of the new library that was added?

Comment: Xcode is shipped with 2 versions of the standard c++ library. They are incompatible. If some libraries are compiled with one, and another with the other, you will get this error. The change happened with the introduction of the clang compiler around Xcode version 4.2